# How do I make the elements in my UIView responsive?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard

My goal is to create an alert that has three text fields, one taller than the others, and an image that, when tapped, allows the user to choose a picture to replace a set default one.

After unsuccessfully searching for a library for this, I decided to create my own alert by placing a `UIView` off the screen and, when prompted by a button, would zoom onto the screen; it consists of all the elements I require.

When I run the application, the view pops up correctly, but none of the elements on the view are responding to touch. I've checked that `isUserInteractionEnabled` for everything is turned on.

What's also odd is that when I keep the view on the screen (instead of placing it some distance away on *Storyboard*), all the elements work fine.

I'm assuming it had something to do with the animation. I tested it with a fade in instead of a displacement, and the result was the same - the elements were unresponsive.

Comment: Have you checked whether your alert view has any other views in front of it? If you could post some code that would be useful.

Comment: are those non-responsive elements _inside_ your view's actual bounds?

Comment: @Sparky it doesn't; I know this because when the alert zooms onto view, it's shown in front of all of the other elements in the view controller. I don't have any relevant code for this issue except for maybe a screenshot of where the view is on the storyboard. The animation code is irrelevant, I think, because it didn't work when I did a simple fade by messing with the alpha of the view and when I did a more complicated animation with an animation library called pop.

Comment: @holex on the storyboard, they're outside of the bounds but brought in through an animation. I also did a test where I kept it in bounds and did a fade instead and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your elements to be responsive you have to link the action of you clicking them to your view's code. You can do this in a non-programmatic manner by ctrl-clicking your element on story-views and then dragging to the view controller. Then choose action instead of outlet, and choose when the action you want will be triggered (bottom part). Then insert your code in the viewController.

Comment: They are linked programmatically. Actually, I'm pretty sure even if they weren't, it should still be responsive. An unconnected button still is clickable, but doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I used the debug view hierarchy and saw that the alert was behind the elements behind it, even though it was still being shown (for some reason). I changed the zIndex of the UIView and it worked!